# Fire Method When Last Block Returns

Tags: ios, block

How I do fire a method when I am confident both block codes have returned? Like so...

```
// Retrieve Messages Array from Parse
[ParseManager retrieveAllMessagesForShredderUser:(ShredderUser *)[PFUser currentUser] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSArray *objects){
        self.messagesArray = objects;
    }];

// Retrieve MessagesPermissions Array from Parse
[ParseManager retrieveAllMessagePermissionsForShredderUser:(ShredderUser *)[PFUser currentUser] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSArray *objects){
        self.messagePermissionsArray = objects;
    }];

-(void)methodToRunWhenBothBlocksHaveReturned{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the blocks will be executed on the same thread (i.e., the UI thread), then the alternative is simple, using a `__block` variable.

```
-(void)yourMethod {
    __block int count = 0;
    [ParseManager retrieveAllMessagesForShredderUser:(ShredderUser *)[PFUser currentUser] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSArray *objects){
        self.messagesArray = objects;
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
             [self methodToRunWhenBothBlocksHaveReturned];
        }
    }];

    [ParseManager retrieveAllMessagePermissionsForShredderUser:(ShredderUser *)[PFUser currentUser] withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error, NSArray *objects){
        self.messagePermissionsArray = objects;
        count++;
        if (count == 2) {
             [self methodToRunWhenBothBlocksHaveReturned];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)methodToRunWhenBothBlocksHaveReturned{
}
```

If you don't have the same-thread guarantee, you can use a [lock](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to make sure that the increment of the variable (and the comparison to 2) will be atomic.